# Getting Wiris editor to display without popup

Tags: text-editor, rich-text-editor

I am trying to integrate Wiris into my website without requiring users to click their editor button and opening the equation editor in a popup. Does anyone have experience doing this? Do I need to add it as a plugin for CKEditor or can Wiris do this with a basic textarea? I have tried to search here and their website but have not found the information I need. I am not committed to Wiris if there is another plugin that can accomplish the same outcome. Any help is really appreciated.

[image: Wiris Editor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using our editor embedded: http://www.wiris.com/editor/docs/resources/embed-editor

You can follow this example: http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/tests/files/test15.html

As you can see in the source code of the example, upon clicking on a page element (in this case they are simple buttons but you could use images), it calls `editor1.action('<action>')` where `<action>` would be any of our toolbar button IDs and then `editor1.focus()`. For example, `editor1.action('fraction');editor1.focus();`. You can also add your custom MathML (like the Right brackets button does in the example) or symbols.

Comment: By the way, this is the list of our toolbar button IDs: http://www.wiris.net/demo/editor/docs/toolbar/